# Paypal Adaptive Payments PPConnectionException in PPHttpConnection.php

Tags: php, laravel, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I currently try to implement chained payments using the adaptive payments sdk. I receive this error

```
PPConnectionException in PPHttpConnection.php line 91:
error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

My example code looks like this

```
$payRequest = new \PayPal\Types\AP\PayRequest();

    $receiver = array();
    $receiver[0] = new \PayPal\Types\AP\Receiver();
    $receiver[0]->amount = '7.50';
    $receiver[0]->email = "admin@example.de";

    $receiver[1] = new \PayPal\Types\AP\Receiver();
    $receiver[1]->amount = '2.50';
    $receiver[1]->email = "seller@example.de";
    $receiver[1]->primary = "true";
    $receiverList = new \PayPal\Types\AP\ReceiverList($receiver);
    $payRequest->receiverList = $receiverList;

    $requestEnvelope = new \PayPal\Types\Common\RequestEnvelope("de_DE");
    $payRequest->requestEnvelope = $requestEnvelope;
    $payRequest->actionType = "PAY";
    $payRequest->cancelUrl = "http://example.de:8080/payment/cancel";
    $payRequest->returnUrl = "http://example.de:8080?returned";
    $payRequest->currencyCode = "EUR";
    $payRequest->ipnNotificationUrl = "http://example.de:8080";

    $sdkConfig = array(
        'mode' => 'sandbox',
        "acct1.UserName" => "jb-us-seller_api1.paypal.com",
        "acct1.Password" => "WX4WTU3S8MY44S7F",
        "acct1.Signature" => "AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31A7yDhhsPUU2XhtMoZXsWHFxu-RWy",
        "acct1.AppId" => "APP-80W284485P519543T"
    );

    $adaptivePaymentsService = new \PayPal\Service\AdaptivePaymentsService($sdkConfig);
    $payResponse = $adaptivePaymentsService->Pay($payRequest);

    if ($payResponse->responseEnvelope->ack == "Success")
    {
        redirect('Location: ' . 'https://sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_ap-payment&paykey=' . $payResponse->payKey);
    }
    else{
        die('error');
    }
```

The solutions I found do not seem to work ... any ideas? Currently testing from localhost.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of the actual solution or cause of the error.

What fixed it for me was testing it on an actual server instead of my localhost enviroment.

I also updated the packages to the latest version since there were many changes regarding tls. Older examples do not reference working libaries.